# How to access nested NSDictionary data from FireBase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

I am running an Xcode 8 / Swift 3 program pulling data from a firebase database.  I am adding "Brands" into a "Store" Detail.

Here is what the data looks like:

[image: NSDictionary Screenshot]

I am able to access all of the "root" data such as locality and thoroughfare using the following code.

```
let storeName = value["StoreName"] as! String
let subThouroughfare = value["subThouroughfare"] as! String
let thouroughfare = value["Thouroughfare"] as! String
let administrativeArea = value["administrativeArea"] as! String
```

I am not sure how to access the embedded data, and eventually there will be more then one "Brand" key with 4 values structured as such:

```
$StoreKey:
    brands:
        $brandKey1:
            Value1: String
            Value2: String
            Value3: String
            Value4: String
        $brandKey2:
            Value1: String
            etc...
```

So far I have a Struct setup as the following and I will need to query the brand from the brand part of the table:

```
var ProductList = [storeStruct]()
struct BrandStruct{
    let BrandKey: String
    let BrandName: String
    let Value1: String
    let Value2: String
    let Value3: String
    let Value4: String
}
```

What is the best way to get at that data and structure it into a useable array so I can fill a table?  Or should I keep trying to query the Firebase until I get something I can use?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not sure how to dive deeper into the dictionary.  Right now I am pull data from the first layer of the dictionary, but I am not sure how to get the brand Key and values.

Comment: Restructure and reframe your question with your actual query , your question is unclear, delete unwanted details, and include your actual JSON structure

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the question. See if my answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by fetching `let brands = value["brands"] as! NSDictionary`, completely parallel to what you're already doing. Now ask for `brands.allKeys`; that's an array of the brand keys. For each key, you can then ask for `brands[thisKey] as! NSDictionary` and you'll get back the dictionary containing the four values keyed on `"Val1"`, `"Val2"`, `"Val3"`, and `"Val4"`. (Again, if the names and quantity of these keys can vary, `allKeys` will tell you what they are.)

Comment: Ok I see where you are going with this one, and I seem to be making progress.  Thanks for your help.  As soon as I am done programming my block, I will let you know.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I've tried to keep it as simple as possible; in real life I would cast to `[String:Any]` instead of NSDictionary, and I would then use `keys` to get the keys, but it doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: This worked out.  I was able to pull all the values out an add it to an array.  Thanks.